# how to convert javascript array to php array

Tags: php, javascript

here is the code to convert javascript array to php array..... this is done with cookies...

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
    var a_php = "";
    var a=new Array(); 
/*

a[0]="Saab";       
a[1]="Volvo";
a[2]="BMW";
a[3]="sample"

a[4]="Saab";       
a[5]="Volvo";
a[6]="BMW";
a[7]="sample"


a[8]="Saab";       
a[9]="Volvo";
a[10]="BMW";
a[11]="sample"


a[12]="Saab";       
a[13]="Volvo";
a[14]="BMW";
a[15]="sample"

a[16]="Saab";       
a[17]="Volvo";
a[18]="BMW";
a[19]="sample"

a[20]="Saab";       
a[21]="Volvo";
a[22]="BMW";
a[23]="sample"

a[24]="Saab";       
a[25]="Volvo";
a[26]="BMW";
a[27]="sample"
*/

for(var t=0;t<350;t++)
    a[t]="hello"+t;


    for(var count=0;count<a.length;count++)
        a_php = a_php+a[count]+",";
    setCookie("new_cookie1",a_php,3);


}
</script>
```

is there any possible way to convert javascript array to php without cookies....

Comment: json encode then store into the cookie, decode back in php

Comment: @Marcel Korpel @Luzhin @venimus i need to convert javascript array to php array without using cookies... how can we do that.... any efficient way??.........

Comment: i assume you will use it in a PHP script, then you could use `a_php=encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(a))` then use a_php as a GET or POST parameter to the php script that uses it. there you decode it with `json_decode(rawurldecode($_GET['a_php']))`

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it is not possible to change server side to change output to json. I had input in the form i.e. 
`[ ['azz2465014416', '8', '22'],['azz2465014418', '10', '22'],['azz2465014420', '12', '22'],['azz2465014422', '14', '22'] ]`

and I get php array from this input using this php code:

```
<?php
$a = "[ ['azz2465014416', '8', '22'],['azz2465014418', '10', '22'],['azz2465014420', '12', '22'],['azz2465014422', '14', '22'] ]";

$b = '$c = '.(str_replace(array('[',']'),array('array(',')'),$a)).';';
eval($b);
print_r($c);
```

you will have then in varible $c resulted output. This is not ideal solution. It will not cover every javascript array, but if you have trouble with some array, you can change it to cover your situation.

Answer (score 6):

In JS:

```
var a, s;
a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three'];
s = JSON.stringify( a );

//Do something to send `s` to the server in a request
```

In PHP, assuming `s` came from client in a cookie

```
<?php
$a = json_decode( $_COOKIE['s'], true );
```

Simple as that.

Comment: i need to convert javascript array to php array without using cookies... how can we do that.... any efficient way??.........

Comment: This is the correct solution. Just use `json_decode($JSArrayString, true)`... simple!

Answer (score 4):

You Should Post it to another(or current) page to be processed with PHP. If you don't want page to be redirected Use AJAX to send Array to PHP.

Comment: @Amir i need to convert javascript array to php array without using cookies... how can we do that.... any efficient way??.........

Comment: I didn't talk about cookies. Directly send array using POST and then parse with php.

Comment: I told u so. I always use jQuery and I pass array using a single string(keys and values in format of csv like) and then split using PHP

Comment: or maybe just JSON.stringify() ;)
Dinosaurs :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON to do this. 
On the JavaScript-side, just use `JSON.stringify(theArray);` to create a JSON-representation of that array. 
In PHP you can use `json_decode(theString, true);` to get the array
Links: 
http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: i need to convert javascript array to php array without using cookies... how can we do that.... any efficient way??.........

Comment: @learn: Oh please, did you actually read these answers and try something yourself? You're merely copying the same comment over and over again.

Comment: @learn: See http://www.json.org. I **strongly** advice you to read a good JavaScript book before going on.