# javascript array converted to a php array?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I convert a javascript array to a php array??

I have a javascript array which I want to put the values into a php array
please help me?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please use the search (I'm writing from my phone otherwise I would already have provided a duplicate... (I'm sure this was asked before))

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330830/how-to-convert-javascript-array-to-php-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would typically convert the array to a JSON string with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), then make an AJAX request to the server, receive the string parameter and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to get back an array in the PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

here is the (very) basic idea.

javascript

```
var arr=your array;
var str;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

    str+='&array_items[]='+arr[i];
}
document.location.href='url.php?'+str;
```

php

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_GET['array_items']); $i++){ 

    $arr[] = $_GET['array_items'][$i];

}

//display php array on page
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX it. Just like anything else you want to send to the server without a full page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the javascript to a PHP object too...

```
/**
* Takes a json encoded string and turns it into a PHP object
* 
* @param string string
* @return object
*/
public static function jsonToPhp($string)
{
    $obj = json_decode(stripslashes($string));
    if (!is_object($obj))
    {
        $obj = json_decode($string);
        if (!is_object($obj))
        {
            print "Cannot convert $string to an object";
                            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Requires that your javascript be converted to json.