# Converting Javascript Array to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to get data from import io in php format, however that doesn't work with pagination, so have had to do it in javascript (code below) however i need to put it into a database so I guess php would be the best (or at least easiest for me).  My question is how can i convert a javascript array into a php array.

thanks,

MsKazza

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Import&bull;io Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1. Include the client library -->
  <script src="https://cdn.import.io/js/2.0.0/importio.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure the library -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    importio.init({
      "auth": {
        "userGuid": "4e3524b0-5ff7-4102-9710-f96246a8303c",
        "apiKey": "oX9ksC/OQXxeO6dXYlNTgl8Juuh2SkCpdih2f0xH9d+3tzoBT0CsFuLr+ZlWPxVLbylL9XHQ8dLxNJvrKc2AUg=="
      },
      "host": "import.io"
    });

    // Data and done callbacks
    var dataCallback = function(data) {
      console.log("Data received", data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        for (var k in d.data) {
          document.write("<i>" + k + "</i>: " + d.data[k] + "<br />");
        }
        document.write("<hr>");
      }
    }
    var doneCallback = function(data) {
      console.log("Done, all data:", data);
      document.write("<b>Done</b><hr>");
    }

// 3. Do the query (when the function is called)
    var doQuery = function() {
      // Query for tile goldenwherewhen
      importio.query({
        "connectorGuids": [
          "83c211ab-91a1-4e54-9838-dc086bc1b527"
        ],
        "input": {
          "what": "hotels",
          "where": "ireland"
        }
      }, { "data": dataCallback, "done": doneCallback });

    }
  </script>
  <style>body { text-align: center; } button { line-height: 20px; color: #333; text-align: center; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #CCC; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); outline: 0; padding: 11px 19px; font-size: 17.5px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; color: #FFF; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); background-color: #EC3C87; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#EE4E93,#E92076); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#EE4E93),to(#E92076)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#EE4E93,#E92076); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#EE4E93,#E92076); background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#EE4E93,#E92076); background-repeat: repeat-x; border-color: #E92076 #E92076 #AC1153; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffee4e93',endColorstr='#ffe92076',GradientType=0); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false); }</style>
  <body>
    <button onClick="doQuery()">Query</button>
    <p style="margin-top: 0"><img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see an array. I only see a chunk of code. Are we supposed to execute it to see what the array looks like?

Comment: I won't waste too much time looking at your code but I suggest you use JSON. Convert your array into JSON string and then send it to PHP, where it can be converted to array using json_decode(). See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: this question is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880904/javascript-array-converted-to-a-php-array

Comment: i'm sorry i don't usually work with javascript i assumed it was as the output looks like an array.  Please see : http://adlantic.ie/importio/goldenwherewhen.html for output.  If its not then how can i convert this to php to extract info.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, two of the "best" would be

1, sending variables in the format `variable[key] = value` php will reconise this and do the the conversion so `$_GET['variable']['key']` would contain `value`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

2, send it as a JSON string use `JSON.stringify(yourArray);` (NOTE: IE8 and above support this, older versions need a libary like json2), then in php call json_decode() on the variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php