# Convert Javascript array to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm creating PHP scraper to get value from Javascript array, how to Convert Javascript array to PHP Array

```
<?php
// example scraped array
$str = 'var str_array = ["aa", "bb"]';
$str = str_replace("var ", '$', $str); 
eval($str);
print_r($str_array);
```

Comment: but js is client side  after converting its not `print` of array using `print_r`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert javascript array to php array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330830/how-to-convert-javascript-array-to-php-array)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Update `eval($str);` into `eval("$str;");`

Comment: I need js string to process in the server, it not for client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) should end with `;`

```
<?php
$str = 'var str_array = ["aa", "bb"]';
$str = str_replace("var ", '$', $str); 
eval($str.";");
print_r($str_array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => aa [1] => bb )
```

But I don't know why you opt for this.

Answer (score 4):

Post your javascript array as a JSON string via ajax and process it server-side.

**Javascript**

```
var str_array = ["aa", "bb"];
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { myData : JSON.stringify(str_array) },
  dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
  // ajax response
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

**PHP (test.php)**

```
$json = $_POST['myData'];
$myDataArray = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($myDataArray);
```